# AWS CLI docker: parameters are not formatted correctly

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I need to make some work with docker and AWS.

when I try to run

> $ docker run --rm -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY grycap/aws-cli ec2 describe-instances

I get:

> An error occurred (AuthFailure) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: Authorization header or parameters are not formatted correctly.

But my $aws configure is already done; when I run

```
$aws configure list
```

I get:

```
Name                    Value             Type    Location
----                    -----             ----    --------
profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key     ****************3Y7Q shared-credentials-file
secret_key     ****************yCIY shared-credentials-file
region           ap-southeast-2      config-file    ~/.aws/config
```

Edit:
when I try

> > > echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID

the response is an empty line...

Comment: can you share output of `echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` from host machine ? is it showing your actual access_keys ?

Comment: It seems like you should use `docker run -it -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY -e AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION  grycap/aws-cli ec2 describe-instances`

Comment: hi @chintanthakar, thanks for the reply, trying echo, returns empty line

Comment: yes that's the reason you are getting Authentication error. you first have to `export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<Your-Actual-key> and same for $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION ` than you have to run the command `docker run --rm -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY grycap/aws-cli ec2 describe-instances` it will work definitely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the complete solutions.

`export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<Your-Actual-key>
 export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<Your-Actual-key>
 export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=<Your-Actual-Region>`

And than run command below :

```
docker run --rm -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY grycap/aws-cli ec2 describe-instances
```

Alternatively You can put all these three in `~/.bash_profile`

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<Your-Actual-key>; export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<Your-Actual-key> ; export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=<Your-Actual-Region> ;export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
```

`source ~/.bash_profile` and than run command :

```
docker run --rm -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY grycap/aws-cli ec2 describe-instances
```

hope this will help.
Thank You!